# NetSuite - Search customers by complex query

Tags: c#, netsuite

I am trying to search customers who contain these fields : email **or** firstName **or** lastName **or** id.

must be an **OR** condition between of them.

for example

```
var freeText = "shomeone@gmai";
var customers = SearchForCustomersWhoContainsThisData(freeText)
```

how can i build this query in c#?

```
public List<Customer> SearchForCustomersWhoContainsThisData(string search_text)
{
    CustomerSearch custSearch = new CustomerSearch();

    SearchStringField searchField = new SearchStringField();
    searchField.@operator = SearchStringFieldOperator.contains;
    searchField.operatorSpecified = true;
    searchField.searchValue = search_text;
    CustomerSearchBasic custBasic1 = new CustomerSearchBasic();
    custBasic1.firstName = searchField;

    CustomerSearchBasic custBasic2 = new CustomerSearchBasic();
    custBasic2.lastName = searchField;

    custSearch.basic = custBasic1;
    //custSearch.basic = custBasic2; how to add this with or between

    // Search for the customer entity who contains this text
    SearchResult response = _crmNetSuitService.search(custSearch);
    var searchResults = response.recordList.Select(t => (Customer)t).ToList();

    return searchResults;
}
```

I expect to find customers who one of these fields contains this **search-text**:
email, fName, lName, Id.

Answer (score 3):

As per NetSuite SuiteAnswers id 31408

**Web Services > Search > How to set a field filter for one value OR another value**

*Currently, expressions are not supported via Web Services searches.
In order to Search where a field is one value or another.  It is necessary to submit two search requests, then merge the results in the application code.*

Comment: Building a RESTlet is an alternate solution.